# {"error":"incident is missing"} when using PATCH or PUT to update an incident

Tags: statuspage-api

When I try to submit a PATCH or PUT request to update an incident, I get:

```
{"error":"incident is missing"}
```

Here is my request:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/xxxx/incidents/lf7****nf2?api_key=xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"incident": "Requests Failed (500)",
"status": "identified"
}'
```

I have also tried with Authorization: Oauth  approach

I am able to create an incident and am also able to list them, so I am unsure what is going on.

I am following https://developer.statuspage.io/#operation/putPagesPageIdIncidentsIncidentId and https://developer.statuspage.io/#operation/patchPagesPageIdIncidentsIncidentId

What am I missing?

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i need to use https://doers.statuspage.io/api/v1/

```
curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/qfn30z5r6s5h/incidents/21w20wsvz5kv.json \
    -H "Authorization: OAuth 2a7b9d4aac30956d537ac76850f4d78de30994703680056cc103862d53cf8074" \
    -X DELETE
```